# Naming columns by mathematical symbols in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add the units of my parameters next to each parameter as the name of a column in my dataframe. I also need to use statistical symbols for some column names such as μ and σ2.

I tried following code according to mathematical symbols in python that is r"$...$ but it does not work for dataframe:

```
P[r"Infiltration rate ($1/\h^-1$)"]=r['ACH_Base']
```

in order to give (1/h^-1) unit to Infiltration rate parameter.
In my code I have already created a new dataframe "P" and I am adding the ACH_Base column in "r" dataframe to P. 
How can I add mathematical symbols for naming the columns in dataframes? 
Thanks!!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Observe the typo you have `r['ACH_Base']`, remove square brackets `r'ACH_Base'`.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but it depends on the backend used to display the dataframe. For instance, matplotlib has support to render LaTeX in plots. 
Here is an example:

https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#text-rendering-with-latex

LaTeX can also be rendered in jupyter notebooks, but this does **not** apply to Python code, only for markdown cells:

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html?highlight=latex#LaTeX-equations

Comment: What do you mean by "in pandas"? You can use the symbols you want in a Python string. The rendering of that string depends on the backed being used (matplotlib or something else). If you want to use "μ" as a name for a column, just use the string "μ" ;)

Comment: I tried the string also but it shows a weird symbol of : I^2/4 instead of the symbol of μ.

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you use? Is the encoding utf-8?

Comment: If you're using Python 2, this is expected as it does not rely on UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 0):

"\h" is an unknown symbol. 
Does `P[r"Infiltration rate ($1/h^-1$)"]=r['ACH_Base']` work to display what you want?

What unit do you wish to display? You can refer to https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html and https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-tutorial for more information on how to render text with LaTex.

Comment: @ For example i want to use the statistical symbol of μ as the name of a column that the mean operation has been done on the parameters. The mathtext.html is exactly what I used to show each symbol. But it does not work when I am using it to name my columns with it in dataframe.